# what is the HTML helper for BsControlType.Upload in BForms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using BForms in a MVC application.

One of the control types is BsControlType.Upload, which I configured in model in a property, however, I have not seen the corresponding HTML helper in order the control to be placed in the page.

I have placed @Html.BsInputFor(s => s.CheckList) bt an error is thrown.

This is the model class:

```
public class ProcesoIncidenciaModel
{
    [BsControl(BsControlType.Number)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Actividad", Prompt = "Escriba la actividad efectuada")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.TextArea)]
    [Required]
    public string Actividad { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Adicionales", Prompt = "Escriba información adicional")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.TextArea)]
    public string Adicionales { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mesa de Ayuda", Prompt = "Escriba quién atendió")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.TextBox)]
    public string MesaAyuda { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Datos de Puntos", Prompt = "Escriba los datos de los puntos")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.TextBox)]
    public string DatosPuntos { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado", Prompt = "Seleccione el estado final")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.DropDownList)]
    [Required]
    public BsSelectList<int?> Estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Check List", Prompt = "Suba la foto del check list")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.Upload)]
    [Required]
    public string CheckList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto", Prompt = "Suba la foto")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.Upload)]
    [Required]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Informe", Prompt = "Adjunte informe")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.Upload)]
    public string Informe { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Presupuesto", Prompt = "Adjunte el presupuesto")]
    [BsControl(BsControlType.Upload)]
    public string Presupuesto { get; set; }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was a bug in BForms

Regards
Jaime